# Average Access time in caches

Tags: computer-architecture, cache

I know that the average access time for systems with level 1 caches is:

Average Access Time = Hit time + (Miss Rate x Miss Penalty)

How can this be generalized for n level caches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly, this is the formula:

Hit time +

(miss rate for cache 1 * (1 - miss rate for cache 2) * miss penalty for cache 1) +

(miss rate for cache 1 * miss rate for cache 2 * miss penalty for cache 2)

Essentially, we just split the case that cache 1 missed into the two cases: cache 2 hit, cache 2 missed.

I believe that if you understand this, it wont be hard to generalize for the $n$ cache levels.